# Playing audio in bluestack app player works fine? but not in device

Tags: android

i am new to android application development. i am developping one project. that contains 100 audio files.  all are i placed in asset folder. for playing audio i take one Mediaplayer class

```
MusicPlayer.java


/** Plays music and one-off sound files while managing the resources efficiently */
public class MusicPlayer {

    private static MusicPlayer mInstance;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private MusicPlayer() { }

    /**
     * Returns the single instance of this class
     *
     * @return the instance
     */
   /* */

    public static MusicPlayer getInstance() {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MusicPlayer();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Plays the sound with the given resource ID
     *
     * @param context a valid `Context` reference
     * @param soundResourceId the resource ID of the sound (e.g. `R.raw.my_sound`)
     */
    public synchronized void play(final Context context, final int soundResourceId) {
        // if there's an existing stream playing already
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            // stop the stream in case it's still playing
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }

            // release the resources
            mMediaPlayer.release();

            // unset the reference
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

        // create a new stream for the sound to play
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), soundResourceId);

        // if the instance could be created
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            // set a listener that is called when playback has been finished
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // if the instance is set
                    if (mp != null) {
                        // release the resources
                        mp.release();

                        // unset the reference
                        mMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }

            });

            // start playback
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        // if there's an existing stream playing already

                mMediaPlayer.stop();

            // release the resources
            mMediaPlayer.release();

            // unset the reference
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

    public synchronized void isPlaying() {
        // if there's an existing stream playing already
if(mMediaPlayer != null)
{
    mMediaPlayer.stop();

    // release the resources
    mMediaPlayer.release();

    // unset the reference

}

    }
}
```

in Activity i used like this

```
MusicPlayer.getInstance().play(Activity.this, R.raw.gajju_urturn);
```

when i run the project in bluestack app player all audio are playing. but when i run in the real device not playing audio and getting the error . plz any one help me to solve the issue.in my logcat shows the following error...

```
12-29 15:02:23.076 219-18360/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
12-29 15:02:23.077 18346-18358/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
12-29 15:02:34.130 219-18366/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
12-29 15:02:34.131 18346-18357/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
12-29 15:02:38.100 219-18368/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
12-29 15:02:38.101 18346-18357/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
12-29 15:02:53.618 219-18370/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
12-29 15:02:53.620 18346-18358/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
12-29 15:03:03.138 219-18373/? E/GenericSource: Failed to init from data source!
12-29 15:03:03.138 18346-18358/? E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with me. Check the resources format, also check if your "raw" directory contains the requested file. Also run your code in a different phone. I have used the same code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MusicPlayer.getInstance().play(this, R.raw.no_promises);
}
```

Comment: thanks man for response..  u r right some files are with extension of .wma